# Gulp: call an async function which provides its own callback from within a transform function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, gulp

I want to create a function for use in a pipe() call in Gulp that'll enable conversion of xlsx files to json.

I had this working with NPM package 'excel-as-json' for gulp 3, however Gulp 4 has forced me to actually understand what it is doing ;-)

Six hours in, and my incapacity of getting this to work due to a lack of js/async/streaming knowledge is punching my curiosity.

Code is as follows:

```
paths = {excel_sourcefiles: "./sourcefiles/*.xls*", excel_targetdir_local_csvjson: "./targetfiles_local/*.*"}


var replaceExt = require('replace-ext');
var PluginError = require('plugin-error')
var gulpFunction = require('gulp-function').gulpFunction // default ES6 export
var through = require("through2")
var convertExcel = require('excel-as-json').processFile;
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
var assign = Object.assign || require('object.assign');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var gulpIgnore = require('gulp-ignore');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('excel-to-jsoncsv', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.excel_sourcefiles)
    // .pipe(debug())
    .pipe(gulpIgnore.exclude("*\~*")) // Ignore temporary files  by Excel while xlsx is  open
    .pipe(gulpIgnore.exclude("*\$*")) // Ignore temporary files  by Excel while xlsx is  open
    .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: notify.onError('gulp-excel-to-jsoncsv error: <%= error.message %>')}))
    .pipe(changed(paths.excel_targetdir_local_glob, { extension: '.csv' }))
    .pipe(GulpConvertExcelToJson()) // This is where the magic should happen
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.csv' })) // Saving as .csv for SharePoint (does not allow .json files to be saved)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.excel_targetdir_local))
});

function GulpConvertExcelToJson() {
  return through.obj(function(chunk, enc, callback) {
    var self = this
    if (chunk.isNull() || chunk.isDirectory()) {
      callback() // Do not process directories
      // return
    }

    if (chunk.isStream()) {
      callback() // Do not process streams
      // return
    }

    if (chunk.isBuffer()) {
      convertExcel(chunk.path, null, null, // Converts file found at `chunk.path` and returns (err, `data`) its callback.
        function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            callback(new PluginError("Excel-as-json", err))
          }
          chunk.contents = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(data))
          self.push(chunk)
          callback()
          // return
        })
    } else {
      callback()
    }
  })
}
```

I (now) know there are other excel > json gulp modules that could allow me to solve this problem without writing my own module, yet I'd like to understand what I should do different here.

The error returned is 'Did you forget to signal Async completion?', which I tried to not do. However, probably my attempt to fix the error 'this.push is not a function' with a `var self = this` is not what I was supposed to do.

Looking at examples like gulp-zip introduced me to unfamiliar notations, making me unable to autodidact my way out of this.

In summary:

- how would I go about calling an async function during a through.obj function call, where the chunk's contents is updated with the (not under my control) async function that only provides me with a callback (err, data)?

Comment: I think it would help if you could create a repo with this and share it with us. It would make things simpler for debugging.

Comment: Makes sense: please see https://github.com/MattTheVV/so-question-gulp-async-function-call-xlsx

Comment: Is excel-as-json is still working? It was written for npm2. It isn't really doing anything when I run it. convertExcel('cols.xlsx', 'rows.csv', {}, (err, data) => {
  console.log(data)
})

Comment: @MattV Like Aniket mentioned, `excel-as-json` has to be updated, but I answered with a workaround. Send me a PM if you want to do that together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is coming deep from the `excel` library. [The `end` event should be `finish`](https://github.com/trevordixon/excel.js/pull/65).

#### Unsuccessful Try

I did the following, to install the modified excel.js:

```
rm -rf node_modules/excel
git clone https://github.com/bdbosman/excel.js node_modules/excel
cd node_modules/excel && npm i && cd ../..
```

This is not enough since the `excel-as-json` uses an old version of `excel`.

Either you have to modify the `excel-as-json` module, to use `excel@1.0.0` (after the Pull Request is merged) or manually edit the file in node_modules. I will describe the second way here.

#### Temporary Solution

Edit the `excel` file after installing the modules.

I used:

```
sed -i "s/'end'/'finish'/g" node_modules/excel/excelParser.js
```

And then I ran:

```
$ gulp excel-to-jsoncsv
[19:48:21] Using gulpfile ~/so-question-gulp-async-function-call-xlsx/gulpfile.js
[19:48:21] Starting 'excel-to-jsoncsv'...
[19:48:21] Finished 'excel-to-jsoncsv' after 126 ms
```

And it apparently worked.